# SVG path (coordinates) for THREE.js

Tags: javascript, css, svg, three.js

I am have taken the exact code from [ThreeJs Example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2.html) which is for generating this [City Model](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=extru#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2).

I have a generated a city boundaries SVG path from Google maps and would like to generate same kind of 3D object using above code. My SVG path code is below

```
"M -378463.90230276587 -216828.5204525995 L -378463.90230276587 -216828.5204525995 L -378468.4733200769 -216800.78018946826 L -378457.36255405867 -216726.32967956597 L -378453.2523036701 -216708.13985810167 L -378446.23084408935 -216645.84207578097 L -378446.40886767313 -216640.48042431887 L -378440.04714254953 -216593.4246023558 L -378428.4180137435 -216539.991347306 L -378408.5945640994 -216510.42896043573 L -378385.51956605876 -216467.31060126523 L -378379.14213297196 -216451.9325052259 L -378359.4495830217 -216424.30743382534 L -378348.87288775464 -216401.72985462152 L -378333.6361633847 -216381.90640497737 L -378337.86684149154 -216373.22513727797 L -378341.7990682963 -216369.96835289372 L -378342.2388912678 -216365.88428244408 L -378331.6883759395 -216327.93384318874 L -378324.9287157465 -216311.89601269213 L -378325.3318868038 -216300.2721198738 L -378321.78712309286 -216297.53893426526 L -378317.28940961056 -216296.21946535073 L -378303.3616821797 -216270.99771233014 L -378293.1933939575 -216243.98001550927 L -378293.88454434136 -216242.82286221522 L -378290.4863882877 -216243.61349636634 L -378276.29162548116 -216233.02632912374 L -378253.8973058489 -216247.0954282241 L -378224.3558629296 -216248.45678504065 L -378204.8989324284 -216228.3558280454 L -378170.660808492 -216241.304425766 L -378170.3675931776 -216235.0578923731 L -378170.22622150823 -216232.0943233032 L -378169.26279976114 -216211.52212740996 L -378152.6542465991 -216208.78370581358 L -378105.9858877301 -216201.0815678245 L -378090.63397162955 -216173.3308327178 L -378065.06664341706 -216168.73363546806 L -378045.64636483014 -216185.9233832709 L -378059.37512472627 -216241.5662251538 L -378059.1971011426 -216244.0742632889 L -378057.3906853668 -216269.52639977072 L -378057.05034616264 -216274.34874449397 L -378054.1391369704 -216315.39365251316 L -378045.7615565607 -216328.4836219031 L -377993.89386184997 -216365.8895184318 L -377991.3072838986 -216367.75353007295 L -377955.1789683823 -216371.94232027777 L -377921.14504796837 -216364.08833864375 L -377920.3229978907 -216362.99925319053 L -377915.61584489804 -216367.39224691782 L -377913.6942373916 -216371.958028241 L -377932.8213006642 -216381.0267590344 L -377936.1670968403 -216393.19519457928 L -377929.9310354229 -216427.5799261728 L -377939.4710051143 -216469.85529131463 L -377948.89578307513 -216477.70927294862 L -377959.25780284416 -216480.447694545 L -377976.6465181818 -216485.03965580696 L -377979.7881108354 -216489.22844601178 L -377976.1229194062 -216505.46000805535 L -377983.93501313817 -216532.14783764756 L -377982.971591391 -216552.4215822387 L -378001.82638330036 -216597.61862854837 L -378000.06709141436 -216607.12194632547 L -378003.0044805454 -216615.18013148196 L -377994.6426080991 -216627.98212154533 L -377998.3287434793 -216637.62681099182 L -378000.4283745695 -216641.8679610742 L -378139.4071975765 -216833.3689772615 L -378144.8997487325 -216840.72030407088 L -378258.3531314292 -216996.0772967787 L -378439.5811396393 -216981.68356643748 L -378444.60768788506 -216944.65466102716 L -378449.5399883511 -216925.05112286875 L -378452.2784099475 -216906.3272306534 L -378452.4773774823 -216884.08475466596 L -378456.9332030626 -216867.26676199373 L -378459.5302529896 -216845.6735484881 L -378462.4571701452 -216837.2540801764 L -378463.90230276587 -216828.5204525995 "
```

If i replace the SVG path from example to the above mentioned, it doesn't even show up. Being completely new to Both `Three.js` and `SVG` i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

So far, my guess is that the SVG coordinates i have in my example are very big and not able to see in viewport. For which i tried to use `transform = translate(-378460px, -216828px)` method. But no luck. Any suggestions ? Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the units from the transform values.

Comment: doesn't work still. BTW is it the right approach ? Do we have any online tools which make those coordinates smaller ?

Answer (score 0):

SVG coordinate system is for (x,y) is x unit to the right and y units down.

Three.js coordinate system for (x,y,z) is x unit to the right, y untis upwards and z units away from you.

You will need to do some sort of transformation either way.

If I am doing a SVG representation for my Three.js for 2D model where I am using the x & z axis as my SVG x,y axis, I will make my SVG mode have a transform="translate(width/w, height/2) scale(1,-1)"

This is to move the (0,0) to the middle of the svg and to make the x,y move in the same direction as the three.js model

Answer (score 0):

You don't see your figure because it's far away from your camera view. I've made some changes in the code of the Threejs example.

1) Added a line which adds a name to a mesh containing an extruded geometry taken from the SVG path. With your SVG path code we will get just a single mesh with the name "mesh00" (in the `addGeoObject` function, the line is `mesh.name = "mesh" + i + j;`)

2) When I know the name of the figure, I can find it

```
var svgObj = scene.getObjectByName("mesh00",true);
```

3) And center it

```
svgObj.geometry.center();
```

Of course, it's up to you how you can make your figure visible for your camera. For example, you can move your camera to the figure or (like I did) bring the figure in front of the camera. The camera is positioned very close in the example, so I moved it further away.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/fewwnd1r/) example

PS. I applied `OrbitControls` to make viewing more comfortable.